# How to active another application window when electron's window hide

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I have a situation about that when my electron app is called win.hide(),I want the latest app which is blur because of show my electron's app to become activity.

I saw some issue at electron's GitHub,it be marked as bug,and still not fixed.
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10023

whether have some solution or idea can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this on Linux. However, as a low effort workaround you could do something like this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

BrowserWindow.prototype.my_hide = function() {
   this.blur();
   this.hide();     
   return;
};

let window = null;
window = new BrowserWindow({...init...});

//at a point where you want to blur and hide your window
window.my_hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question,I saw some reference about this,I realize that it behavior had been defined by Microsoft.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, interesting read. I must say, if this is the default MS way to handle this I think the Electron implementation is right on the money. In consequence, we have the freedom to choose how we want to handle it, e.g. follow the OS or do our own thing.

Comment: Yes,but MS can't provide function on windows10 about make previous window get focus when current window blur ,so i have to change my design in other way:(